# How do I use a for loop to append to a UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

                                                          UITextField *alertTextField = alert.textFields.firstObject;
                                                        NSLog(@"The Number is %@", alertTextField.text);
                                                          int marioNum = [alertTextField.text intValue];
                                                          UITextView *disp = [[UITextView alloc] init];
                                                          CGRect dispFrame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 100);
                                                          disp.frame = dispFrame;
                                                          [self.view addSubview:disp];

                                                          NSMutableString *make = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
                                                          for (marioNum; marioNum>0; marioNum--) {
                                                              [make appendString:@"#"];
                                                              NSLog(@"%@", make);
                                                              disp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", make];

                                                          }
                                                      }];
```

It works when I use NSLog but in the UITextView it just puts them all together with the number I use. For example, if I wanted to use 2, in my NSLog it would come out perfectly like this:

> *
>
> **

But in my UITextView it shows just like

> **

If you still don't understand what I'm trying to do, I wanted to make a program just like the one used at the end of this video but by myself.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZeXSPJfsNPE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop twice, actually (this assumes the information provided in comment under Tj3n answers).

Something like this should work :

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i <= marioNum; i++) {
    for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < i; j++) {        
       [make appendString:@"#"];
    }
    [make appendString:@"\n"];
}

disp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", make];
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try bring `disp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", make];` outside the for-loop, just under it

Comment: That just uses the number at the end of the loop. If I use 3 I'm expecting it to be * ** *** all on different lines. But this just shows ***

Comment: in your `appendString `, add `\n` with it, its the new lines character

Comment: That just prints one star on each line and still only uses the final result and it also does it in NSLog. Thanks for trying to help me though :)

Comment: it's just problem with your string, print your string again after you finish the loop, not while the loop is running

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Comment: move your nslog out of the loop also, if it print correctly, then your text will be correct

Answer (score 0):

yes it will display ** because when the loop is executing every time you are replacing textview's text by this line

```
 disp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", make];
```

to display proper string you need to append that text in textview too. like bellow you need to check disp.text at first time and if its a blank then append simply text other wise append new txt with \n which will append text in new line.

```
  if (disp.text.length > 0) {
        disp.text = [disp.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@", make]];
    }
    else{
        disp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", make];
    }
```

}

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

  UITextField *alertTextField = alert.textFields.firstObject;
  NSLog(@"The Number is %@", alertTextField.text);
  int marioNum = [alertTextField.text intValue];
  UITextView *disp = [[UITextView alloc] init];
  CGRect dispFrame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 100);
  disp.frame = dispFrame;
  [self.view addSubview:disp];
    NSMutableString *make = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
   for (marioNum; marioNum>0; marioNum--) {
        [make appendString:@"#"];
        NSLog(@"%@", make);
     }                                                                                                              
   disp.text = make;

 }];
```